# A "Discord Bot" with tag #0000

Tags: discord.py

I was recently discovering some discord Servers and I saw this:

A Bot with no tag(Or on Mobile #0000)

[image]

How can I do this?(Btw I'm working with `discord.py`)

Comment: Those are webhooks

Answer (score 0):

That is a Discord Webhook and not a Discord `Bot`. It isnt possible to have custom discriminators or no discriminator in your discord bots.